# How to use accelerator table in a subclassed control?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, keyboard-shortcuts

I am subclassing a control and at this point I want to add some keyboard shortcuts to it. There's about a dozen of them defined in an [accelerator table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg153544(v=vs.85).aspx) in the resource.

I know that I can utilize these accelerators from the main app, by calling `TranslateAccelerator` and then `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage` from its main loop.

But can I check if accelerator key sequence is pressed from a subclassed control from within `WndProc` itself?

EDIT: In other words, would it be *bad* to do something like this?

```
LRESULT CSubclassedWnd::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class

    if(message == WM_KEYDOWN ||
        message == WM_CHAR ||
        message == WM_SYSKEYDOWN ||
        message == WM_SYSCHAR)
    {
        if(hAccel)
        {
            CRect rcThis;
            this->GetWindowRect(&rcThis);
            this->ScreenToClient(&rcThis);
            POINT pnt = {(rcThis.right + rcThis.left) / 2, (rcThis.bottom + rcThis.top) / 2};

            MSG msg = {this->GetSafeHwnd(), message, wParam, lParam, ::GetTickCount(), pnt};
            if(::TranslateAccelerator(this->GetSafeHwnd(), hAccel, &msg))
            {
                //Accelerator was recognized and sent as WM_COMMAND message to the same window
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            //Special accelerator commands
            if(HIWORD(wParam) == 1 &&
                lParam == 0)
            {
                //See which command was it
                switch(LOWORD(wParam))
                {
                case ID_MY_ACCELERATOR_ID1:
                    {
                        //Do work...
                    }
                    return 0;

                case ID_MY_ACCELERATOR_ID2:
                    {
                        //Do work...
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        break;

    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        //process it
        return TRUE;
    case WM_PAINT:
        //process it
        return TRUE;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        //process it
        break;

    //etc.
    }

    return CWnd::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the standard Windows controls just use WM_KEYDOWN/CHAR and `GetKeyState` but I don't see why you can't use `TranslateAccelerator`.

`TranslateAccelerator` is in some ways better because it knows how to handle <kbd>Alt.Gr</kbd> but it will also ignore the key if the mouse is captured (IIRC) so it depends on your needs.

Calling `TranslateAccelerator` on the top-level window after `GetMessage` is of course the best option because it will check the window menu to see if the command is disabled...

Comment: Thanks. No, it's not a top level window. The window I'm subclassing is a child window. Part of a dialog window. So it won't have a menu of it's own. The reason I'm asking is because I've never seen `TranslateAccelerator` being called from within a message loop itself.

Comment: You mean never seen it outside the message loop? I know it's not your top level window but it would be better if your top level window could handle all the accelerators.

Comment: Yeah. I meant to say inside `WndProc`.

Comment: @Anders "I believe the standard Windows controls just use WM_KEYDOWN/CHAR and GetKeyState" - How did you arive at this conclusion?

Comment: @phimuemue Probably used a debugger, don't remember. They might also handle WM_SYSCHAR, I don't remember the details anymore. Controls in ComCtl32 are easy to debug, they are fully in user-mode, the old controls are more annoying because they are partially in the kernel.